# Web scraping to obtain pdf reports with beautiful soup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write some web scraping code to search the net for feasability studies of mining companies.  As a starting point I would like reports that are PDF.
what I have so far is below but I get an error with the last line

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Set the search query
query = 'mining companies pre-feasibility feasibility studies'

# Set the URL of the search results page
url = 'https://www.google.com.au/search?q=' + query

# Set the user-agent to avoid being detected as a scraper
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}

# Send a GET request to the search results page
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse the HTML content of the search results page with Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find all the search result links
links = soup.find_all('a')

# Filter the links to those that point to PDF documents
pdf_links = [link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('.pdf')]
```

The error I get is Keywork 'href'

where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select only links that have `href=` attribute:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Set the search query
query = 'mining companies pre-feasibility feasibility studies'

# Set the URL of the search results page
url = 'https://www.google.com.au/search?q=' + query

# Set the user-agent to avoid being detected as a scraper
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}

# Send a GET request to the search results page
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse the HTML content of the search results page with Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find all the search result links
links = soup.select('a[href]')

# Filter the links to those that point to PDF documents
pdf_links = [link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('.pdf')]
print(pdf_links)
```

Prints:

```
['https://www.nzpam.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/permits/minerals-guidelines/guideline-scoping-pre-feasibility.pdf']
```

Comment: It seemed to work, although when I ran it I did not get any results. I guess I will need to expand my search parameters